# Using rsync to synchronize directories

Tags: centos, rsync, backup

I have a script that I am using to backup a directory on a CentOS 6 machine.

It's very basic but it is executing

```
rsync -a remote:~/original ./backup
```

This works fine: it is copying the contents of the original into the backup. However. when something is deleted from the original, it is still present in the backup.

I was wondering if it is possible for `rsync` to make ensure that both directories have the same contents regardless of whether items have been added or deleted.

Deleting the backup directory contents before the `rsync` is not an option because the directories are huge.

Comment: You mean if files get deleted in origin you want them deleted in destination as well. For that you use option --delete.

Comment: wow, that was the best possible answer I couldve hoped for. post an answer with the complete command so i can select it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have files deleted in destination when they are deleted in origin, you use the --delete option.

```
rsync -vaz --delete <origin_folder> <destination_folder>
```

Now destination will delete items within it when origin does.

Answer (score 1):

There are several delete options to choose from here is the extract from the `man rsync` page.

```
        --delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
        --delete-before         receiver deletes before xfer, not during
        --delete-during         receiver deletes during the transfer
        --delete-delay          find deletions during, delete after
        --delete-after          receiver deletes after transfer, not during
        --delete-excluded       also delete excluded files from dest dirs
```